# Observable array isn't supplying data to my table in the front-end

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SequoiaCG</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="knockout-3.3.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="assets/js/testing.js"></script>
    <table>
        <thead><tr>
            <th>First name</th><th>Last name</th>
        </tr></thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: contactGrid">
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: firstName"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: lastName"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

testing.js:

```
function contact(fName, lName) {
    var self = this;
    self.firstName = fName;
    self.lastName = lName;
}

function contactsViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.contactGrid = ko.observableArray([
        new contact("Bob", "Marley"),
        new contact("Testing", "123")
        ]);
}

ko.applyBindings(new contactsViewModel());
```

I tried to move the reference to `testing.js` higher in the HTML file because I thought that maybe the table is being written before the JS file has a chance to run. But it looks like that didn't make a difference. If I place it too high, I get an error. If I place it as the first item in the HTML's body tag, it still doesn't show me any results. I'm wondering if I missed a step in proper data-binding with Knockout.js? I'd appreciate any tips.

Comment: Tried placing `<script src="assets/js/testing.js"></script>` just before `</body>`?

Comment: The code seems to be working fine in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/au2wsmwu/). Check the console output for any errors, maybe some file is not loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the code you posted is that you're calling `ko.applyBindings` before the DOM might be ready, e.g. before the `table` is even known to the browser. Try doing this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    // Add `testing.js` contents here.
});
```

Or with jQuery for better cross-browser compat:

```
$(function() {
    // Add `testing.js` contents here.
});
```

Note that only `applyBindings` technically needs to be deferred till after the DOM's loaded, the other bits you've posted are fine before that.

If you use a jsfiddle like [the one @dotnetom posted in a comment](https://jsfiddle.net/au2wsmwu/) the default is that code is executed `onLoad` as well (see the top-left "Frameworks & Extensions" settings). If you change that default to be as close to the situation you describe in your question (load scripts in the head section) you get the same problems you describe: see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hz2auLwc/).

A final "fix" could also be the one suggested by @Dandy, that is to place your `script` tag below the relevant DOM bits. However, if possible, I'd advise being more explicit and not fire your code until after the DOM's been loaded with one of the approaches above.